# Remove overflowing clickable area

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar with a certain height and a logo that overflows. This logo is, of course, clickable, but it means that the part that overflows, is also clickable.

Is it possible to make the logo overflow, but not the clickable area?

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h4bUdrZ.png" />
    </div>
  </a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
} 

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -36px;
  left: -39px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/67s4ajqf/)

Comment: If you give the a tag to image then it will create problem...

Comment: You have option to make image small in height and width which will not contain any extra space

Comment: Explain yourself @HarshSanghani? I need the image to be as it is now, but I don't want the area OUTSIDE of the nav-bar to be clickable.

Comment: You have to take 2 images 1) for shape 2) for logo then make logo image clickable and you can set shape image as backgroud image....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -36px;
  left: -39px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h4bUdrZ.png" />
    </div>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: After I changed the `100%` on the `a` to `100px`, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just move logo outside of your link and put that link on rest of header:

```css
body,
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -36px;
  left: -39px;
}
a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">
  </a>

  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h4bUdrZ.png" />
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't place the whole `div` inside the `a`.

Place the link after the image, give it absolute positioning and carefully set the position and size.

The other answers make the whole header clickable. If it is not desired, use this solution. You may have to adjust the width of the clickable area.

See the example below:

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
} 

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -36px;
  left: -39px;
}

a.clickable-logo {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 36px;
  top: 36px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h4bUdrZ.png" />
      <a href="#" class="clickable-logo">
      </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In HTML 5 it's perfectly legal to wrap it the way I did.

Comment: Corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change little bit of you structure.

Put `<a>` independent and pass link in it with following css.

**HTML**

```
<nav>
  <a href="#"></a>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h4bUdrZ.png" />
    </div>  
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
} 
nav a{
  position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
} 

.logo {
  position: absolute;
    top: -36px;
    left: -39px;
}
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/67s4ajqf/3/

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="clear">
</div>
</a>
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/h4bUdrZ.png" />
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
} 
.clear {
  height: 100px;
  background: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: -36px;
  left: -39px;
}
```